# Is there a way to filter questions with a minimum score value in RSS feeds

Tags: support, feature-request, rss

I would like to define an RSS feed showing questions scoring 3 or larger.
Similar to what is possible in [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20score%3A3%20is%3Aquestion).
What I have tried is the following but that is not working.

[https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=newest&score=3](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2B%2B&sort=newest&score=3)